# A Recursive sequence that has finite distinct terms {solved}

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

The Question is like this-

We are given  $f(x)= 4x- x^2$. Now , we define a sequence $ x_1, x_2 \cdots $ such that
$ x_n= f (x _ {n-1}) $.
We need to determine how many values of  $x_0$  exist such that the sequence defined above has only finitely many distinct terms .

My Try-
I tried to repeatedly sub the values to get the expressions down to $x_0$ but I realized that is too inefficient.  I do not know much on operating with recursions, so I cannot do much else.

Comment: Hint to get started: show that if any $x_j$ is negative, then the sequence has infinitely many distinct terms.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks!